# Lua insert multiple variables into a table

Tags: variables, insert, lua, lua-table

My question is how (or if) you can insert two values into a lua table.

I got a function that returns (a variable number of values)

```
function a(x, y)
   return x, y
end
```

and another function that inserts that points into a table,

```
function b(x, y)
   table.insert(myTable, x, y)
end
```

So how can i make, that i can call function b with a variable number of arguments and insert them all into my table?

Comment: As currently written, function `b` inserts the value `y` at position `x`.  Is that your intent?  If you want to insert multiple values into a table, you have to call `table.insert` multiple times.  [This page](http://www.luafaq.org/#T1.23) describes how to handle a variable number of arguments to a function; does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last parameter for your function is `...` (called a vararg function), the Lua interpreter will place any extra arguments into `...`. You can convert it to a table using `{...}` and copy the keys/values into your global table named `myTable`. Here's what your function would look like:

```lua
function b(...)
  for k, v in pairs({...}) do
    myTable[k] = v
  end
end

b(1, 2) -- {[1] = 1, [2] = 2} is added to myTable
```

You should tweak the function depending on whether you want to replace, merge or append elements into `myTable`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`select`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-select) function operates on the vararg `...`

```
function b(...)
  for i = 1, select('#',...) do
    myTable[#myTable+1] = select(i,...)
  end
end
```

This will ignore `nil`s in `...`. `myTable` is assumed to be a sequence (no `nil`s between non-`nil` values; `{1, nil, 3}` would not be a sequence) for this to insert the values in the correct order.

E.g.,

```
> myTable = {'a','b'}
> b('c','d')
> for i = 1, #myTable do print(myTable[i]) end
a
b
c
d
>
```

Comment: As a slightly remark, calling `b(1,2,nil,4)` produces the table `{[1] = 1, [2] = 2, [3] = 4}`. It can be good, or bad, depending on the requirements.

Comment: A funny theoretical edge case: If `myTable` has holes (is not a proper sequence), `b` may fill them in *any order* ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
function tableMultiInsert (list, ...)
  for i, v in ipairs({...}) do
    list[#list+1] = v
  end
end

local list = {}
tableMultiInsert (list, 'a', 'b')
print (table.concat (list, ',')) -- a, b
tableMultiInsert (list, 'c', 'd')
print (table.concat (list, ',')) -- a,b,c,d
```

Comment: Downvoted. Overriding `table.insert` like this will massively break existing code that uses the index parameter. Small side note: This doesn't deal with `nil`s in `...` properly; it will stop at the first `nil` (it should ideally either ignore `nil`s, or throw an error).

Comment: Thanks, you are right! Fixed the code as new function instead of table.insert.