# Lua add table line to table with multiple variables

Tags: variables, lua, lua-table

```
user = {
        {uid = "IFOZOTj1JXubBSg26nkhW9yHlwU=", coins = 800, dmod = 0, nmod = 0},
        {uid = "nlncgruCSwId39q2TRSjCnEtgQA=", coins = 200, dmod = 1434246406, nmod = 0}
}
```

This is my current table structure.

Now I want to add a new line the keys are static:

```
uid, coins, dmod, nmod
```

and the values are variables

```
_uid, _coins, _dmod, _nmod
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085204/lua-adding-multiple-rows-to-tables) but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
user[#user+1] = { uid=_uid, coins=_coins, dmod=_dmod, nmod=_nmod }
```

Comment: Perfect , thank you very much . I've tried a ton of "solutions," but that's the only functioning.